# How made my function affect the DOM Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, shopify

*Hi*, I have written a webSite on **Shopify** and I want to disable my button and add some customs CSS class to my input if the input is not filled on my 4steps form.
I've written a piece of code with what I remember from Jquery it's been a long time since I've used this language.

**This is the jQuery funct:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  
  $("#submitButton, #btn0, #btn1, #btn2").click(function () {
    ValidateForm();
  });


  function ValidateForm() {

    var invalidForm = false;
    var index = 0;
    var button = document.querySelector("#submitButton, #btn0, #btn1, #btn2");

    $("#form__form--stepForm-" + index + "input.form__form--input").each(function () {
      if ($(this).val() < 1) {
        invalidForm = true;
      }
    });

    if (invalidForm === true) {
      button.disabled = true;
      $("input.form__form--input").removeClass(".form__form--validation").addClass(".form__form--validationInvalid");

    } else if (invalidForm === false) {
      button.disabled = false;
      $("input.form__form--input").removeClass(".form__form--validation").addClass(".form__form--validationValid");
      index++;
    }
  }
});
```

**I made all my inputs like this one:**

```
<div class="3/3 3/3--thumb 3/3--pocket grid__cell--center">
    <input type="text" id="form__form--lastnameInput" name="contact[lastname]"
    class="form__form--input form__form--validation" placeholder="Nom *" value required>
    <div class="form__form--invalidFeedback">Veuillez saisir votre nom.</div>
</div>
```

**And the button like this:**

```
<button id="btn0" type="button" class="button button--primary form__form--button"
    aria-label="SUIVANT" title="SUIVANT">
    {% include 'icon-arrow-slider' %}
    SUIVANT
</button>
```

As you can see it's a very basic function for the jquery and a classic HTML input but it doesn't block the button and doesn't make the CSS work either. I'd like to understand why and how to make it work for this site and the following thanks for your time and help, take care of yourself!

Comment: is there a form tag around your div? Can you show us?

Comment: there is one only `<form id="form__form--contactWrapper" class="form__form--contactWrapper">` @vincent-d

Answer (score 0):

Your value checking is always false, consider using length function instead:

```
 if ($(this).val().length < 1) {
    invalidForm = true;
  }
```

You may also need to prevent default behavior of your form. Instead of listening to the click, listen the submit event:

```
$("#form__form--contactWrapper").on('submit',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //the form is not sent yet
    ValidateForm();
  });
```

Then at the end of your function `ValidateForm` you can send it when you have all your needed validations done, like this:

```
$("#form__form--contactWrapper").submit();
```

Comment: I agree for the first snippet i was checking if the value was false.
For the second i have to check on the `'click'` event bc i have only the last button of the form with the `type: submit` cause with Shopify a `type: submit` send the whole form to the server so all the button are with the `type: button` !

Comment: it's not clear, does it answer your question? :) if yes, don't forget to mark that answer as "good answer" by click on the check bellow the up and downvote buttons

Comment: i have put the update i have try to do but it's still not working @vincent-d

Answer (score 0):

I have get rid of all error by doing a big refacto of my code i share you my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[to-step]').on('click', function () {
        var to_step = $(this).attr("to-step");
        var current_step = $(this).closest('[stepform]').attr("stepform");
        var form_error = false;
        if (!($(this).hasClass("previous-btn"))) {
            $('[stepform="' + current_step + '"] .form__form--input').each(function () {
                if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
                    $(this).addClass("input--error");
                    form_error = true;
                } else {
                    $(this).removeClass("input--error");
                }
            });
        }
        if (!form_error) {
            if (current_step < 4 || $(this).hasClass("previous-btn")) {
                $('[stepform').hide();
                $('[stepform="' + to_step + '"]').fadeIn();
            }
        }
    });
    $("#submitButton").on("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if ($("#form__form--radioRgpd:checked").length == 1) {
            $("#contact_form").submit();
        } else {
            $(".form__form--radioRgpdLabel").addClass("label--error");
        }
    });
});
```

this piece of code gonna check at what step i am in my 4 'pages' form and add the proper css class if the form is bad filled or not filled.